# Attribute Error when running Django DetailView

Tags: django, django-templates

```
class results(DetailView):
    model = Location
    template_name = 'results.html'

    def get_object(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(results, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')

        context.update({
            'location': Location.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)
        })

        return context
```

The above function aims at getting the user's input string and display it in `DetailView` after filtering. However, when I run it, the following error message is generated:

```
AttributeError at /collector/results/
'results' object has no attribute 'object'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/collector/results/?q=Hong+Kong
Django Version: 3.1.7
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'results' object has no attribute 'object'
```

Do anyone know what causes the error, and how to fix the code?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with what you override, you want to override [`get_context_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data) not [`get_object`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object):

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(results, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    query = self.request.GET.get('q')

    context.update({
        'location': Location.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)
    })

    return context
```